# Remove specified char from strings in C

Tags: c, string, char

I am making a program that will search in an array of strings, and for each string, it will search for a specified char. If it finds that char, remove it. In this example I want to remove the character 'r'.

Here is the code:

```
void convertStrings(char **line) {
    for (int str = 0; str < MAX_LINE_LENGTH; ++str) {
        for (int ch = 0; ch < MAX_STR_LENGTH; ++ch) {
            if (line[str][ch] == 'r') {
                removeChar(line[str], 'r');
            }
        }
    }
}

void removeChar(char *str, char c) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (str[i]) {
        if (str[i] != c) {
            str[j++] = str[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    str[j]=0;
}
```

I am not sure if the algorithm for the removal of chars is correct, however the main mistake is elsewhere. More specifically, I get a segmentation fault in the line:

```
if (line[str][ch] == 'r') {
```

Why am I getting a seg fault? Also, is the algorithm for removeChar correct?

Here is my main function:

```
int main() {
    char line[3][10] = {"pep", "rol", "rak"};
    printf("%s\n", line[1]);
    convertStrings(line);
    printf("%s\n", line[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_Why am I getting a seg fault?_" -- No idea. We'll have to see more code (Specifically, how do you call `convertStrings` and what are the values of `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` and `MAX_STR_LENGTH`). "_Also, is the algorithm for removeChar correct?_" -- Yes. It seems so.

Comment: are you sure `line` contains exactly `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` lines, and each string contains exactly `MAX_STR_LENGTH` chars?

Comment: Have you allocated enough memory to the object pointed to by the double pointer `line`?

Comment: I added my main function in the question.

Comment: @pk163 , What are the values of `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` and `MAX_STR_LENGTH`?

Comment: MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 1024 and
MAX_STR_LENGTH = 4

Comment: If those variables denote the maximum values, why aren't you using `char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH][MAX_STR_LENGTH] = {...};`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works on my compiler :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024
#define MAX_STR_LENGTH 4
void removeChar(char *str, char c) {
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (str[i]) {
    if (str[i] != c) {
        str[j++] = str[i];
      }
    i++;
}
str[j]=0;
}

void convertStrings(char line[][MAX_STR_LENGTH]) {    //change 1
 for (int str = 0; str < MAX_LINE_LENGTH; ++str) {
    for (int ch = 0; ch < MAX_STR_LENGTH; ++ch) {
        if (line[str][ch] == 'r') {
removeChar(line[str], 'r');
        }
    }
  }
}


int main() {
 char line[3][MAX_STR_LENGTH] = {"pep", "rol", "rak"};   //change 2
 printf("%s\n", line[1]);
 convertStrings(line);
 printf("%s\n", line[1]);
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `line[str][ch]` doesn't exist for all the value you give to `str` and/or `ch`.

You should check the value of `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` and `MAX_STR_LENGTH` and be sure that they are right.

Answer (score 1):

The seg fault may be because you are using the constants "MAX_LINE_LENGTH" and "MAX_STR_LENGTH" however there may have the line length or string length.  I would use the length of the array for the variable str in the first for loop instead of "MAX_LINE_LENGTH" and the length of array[str] instead of "MAX_STR_LENGTH".  Unless each array you are searching has "MAX_LINE_LENGTH" and each string has "MAX_LINE_LENGTH" you will get a set fault.  Hope this helps!

EDIT: you can find the length of the array by dividing the size of the array and the size of the type of the element.

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
```

finding the size of the char pointer is basically the same process.

Comment: Yes but what if not every element in the array has the same size?

Answer (score 1):

You have the array

```
char line[3][10] = {"pep", "rol", "rak"};
```

When you pass it to a function, it gets converted into a pointer of type `char(*)[10]`. So change

```
void convertStrings(char **line) {
```

to

```
void convertStrings(char (*line)[10]) {
```

or

```
void convertStrings(char line[][10]) {
```

An array of arrays (2D array) cannot be converted to a pointer to a pointer(in this case, `char**`)

---

Another problem is that [you mention that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599520/remove-specified-char-from-strings-in-c#comment49268027_30599520) `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` is 1024 and `MAX_STR_LENGTH` is 4. This is wrong as the loop would iterate and you access invalid memory locations. You should make `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` as 3 and `MAX_STR_LENGTH` as 4 as there are 3 strings, each with 4 characters.
You can also pass these variables as parameters to the function `convertStrings`. Change add two more parameters in the declartion of `convertStrings`:

```
void convertStrings(char (*line)[10], int MAX_LINE_LENGTH, int MAX_STR_LENGTH) {
```

or

```
void convertStrings(char line[][10], int MAX_LINE_LENGTH, int MAX_STR_LENGTH) {
```

and call the function from `main` using

```
convertStrings(line, sizeof(line)/sizeof(*line), sizeof(*line)/sizeof(**line)); // `/sizeof(**line)` is 1 and is not needed
```

---

A better way would be to use

```
void convertStrings(int MAX_LINE_LENGTH, int MAX_STR_LENGTH, char line[][MAX_STR_LENGTH]) {
```

or

```
void convertStrings(int MAX_LINE_LENGTH, int MAX_STR_LENGTH, char (*line)[MAX_STR_LENGTH]) {
```

and call the function using

```
convertStrings(sizeof(line)/sizeof(*line), sizeof(*line)/sizeof(**line), line); // `/sizeof(**line)` is 1 and is not needed
```

so that you can avoid using the magic number 10 in your function.

---

You would've certainly got some warnings from your compiler. Pay attention to them. If you did not get warnings, crank up the warnings in your compiler and include warning flags ( like `-Wall` in GCC ).

---

BTW, You can look into the `strchr` function from `string.h` to find if a character exists in a string.

Comment: You are correct about 2D arrays vis a vis double pointers, and that certainly could explain the problem.  It is to be hoped, however, that the OP did not ignore the compiler warning that surely would arise from such misuse, and then pose his question without even mentioning it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger , Added a note about warnings.

Comment: Would it be nicer to make the array of strings a typedef / struct so you need only define it once (and have a single-point of change if you alter the sizes etc.) then define the function as accepting a variable of that type (or a pointer to it)?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a segfault either because array `line` contains fewer than `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` string pointers, or because at least one of the pointed-to strings contains fewer than `MAX_STR_LENGTH` characters; more likely the latter.

Instead of assuming a fixed number of strings of fixed length, you would be better off passing the *actual* number of strings as an argument.  Alternatively, you could add `NULL` as sentinel value at the end of the list.

Moreover, there is no reason whatever to assume that each string is a fixed length.  Look for the terminating character (`'\0'`) to recognize when you've reached the end.  For example:

```
void convertStrings(char **line) {
    for (char **l = line; *l != NULL; l += 1) {
        for (int ch = 0; (*l)[ch]; ch += 1) {
            if ((*l)[ch] == 'r') {
                removeChar(*l, 'r');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your `removeChar()` function looks ok.

Do note, however, that there are library functions that could help with this (e.g. `strchr()`), and that there are various efficiency improvements possible (such as passing to `removeChar()` only the string tail, starting at the first appearance of the character to remove).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you check if you encounter the 'r' character twice? (in both function)
checking once would be enough.

A function to detect the char, and a function to delete it?

I would have done it this way :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void    convertStrings(char *line);
void    removeChar(char *str);

int     main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
        convertStrings(argv[1]);
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    }
    return (0);
}

void    convertStrings(char *line)
{
    for (int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == 'r') removeChar(&(line[i]));
    }
}

void    removeChar(char *str)
{
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        str[i] = str[i + 1];
        i++;
    }
}
```

But here is another one solution with only one function :

```
void convertStringsbis(char *line)
{
    int     delta;
    int     i;


    i = 0;
    delta = 0;
    while (line[i++ + delta] != '\0')
    {
        if (line[i + delta] == 'r')
            delta++;
        line[i] = line[i + delta];
    }
}
```